# Threejs IcosahedronGeometry vertex color

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am trying to change color of a selected vertex dynamically. Referring to https://jsfiddle.net/pmankar/m70cpxes/, I created a IcosahedronGeometry point cloud geometry and on click event I would like to change the color of vertex `100`.

```
document.addEventListener('click', function() {
  mesh.geometry.colorsNeedUpdate = true;
  mesh.geometry.colors[100] = new THREE.Color("rgb(255,0,0)");
  console.log(mesh.geometry);
})
```

Now, I have two questions:

1. How to make the vertex `100` change its colors
2. Why is it showing random color to the point cloud

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declared `var material`, then created `materail = new THREE.PointsMaterial();` and then applied `material` again to your `mesh`. There's a typo: `material` != `materail`.

Also, to have different colors of vertices you have to set colors of them

```
  geometry = new THREE.IcosahedronGeometry(102, detailsLevel);

  var colors = [];
  geometry.vertices.forEach(function(){
    colors.push(new THREE.Color(0xffffff));
  });
  geometry.colors = colors;
```

and then in your material you have to set `vertexColors` as `THREE.VertexColors`

```
material = new THREE.PointsMaterial( { size:4, vertexColors: THREE.VertexColors} );
```

after all, in your "click" event listener you can do

```
mesh.geometry.colors[100].set(0xff0000);
mesh.geometry.colorsNeedUpdate = true;
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/prisoner849/a1zfoxh0/) example

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. So silly of me to make a typo.